# How to send email to registered user in Java EE

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, sendmail

I want to send an email activation link to a registered user. I already set up my `Sendmail.class` which work` perfectly.

Here is the scenario:

1. the user request for registration by providing information via a restful client
2. the restful endpoint gets the request to do some business operation and sends a computed code to the email of the registered user and returns a response saying 'successfully registered'

The problem is that I don't want to wait for the `Sendmail.class` to finish the sending process (it may fail) to return the 'successfully registered message

How can I handle this process using Java EE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code that sends the email in an [@Asynchronous](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) method.

Example:

```
@Stateless
public class EmailSender {

    @Asynchronous
    public void sendMail(...) {
        // send mail here
    }

}
```

From the place where you do your business logic:

```
@Inject
private EmailSender emailSender;

public Foo myBusiness() {
    // Compute stuff

    emailSender.sendMail(stuff); // returns immediately 

    // do other stuff if needed
}
```

See the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-async.htm) for some extra info.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem using JMS it works prefectly an is good for scalability.

Comment: @Arjan Tijms, the link is not working for me, could you please update

Answer (score 0):

Put your e-mail sending code in a thread. Even you can easily use SwingWorker:

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected void done() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
           // Send your e-mail here.
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
```

Comment: swing worker is related to GUI iam in the server side and i want to use JEE standard. this approach seems to be bad as 1000 users may request activation ...

Comment: You can use a normal Thread instead, SwingWorker was just an example, and it was easy. The idea here is to use a thread in sending e-mail.

Comment: some research on internet talk about JMS for sending asynchronous mail. as i told in my previous message using thread is not good for scalability. so i have no idiea on implementing this using JMS help please